# how to convert JSON data to .tsv file using python.

Tags: json, python-3.x, csv

My json data looks like this :

```
data ={
    "time": "2018-10-02T10:19:48+00:00",
    "class": "NOTIFICATION",
    "type": "Access Control",
    "event": "Window/Door",
    "number": -61
}
```

Desired output have to be like this:

```
time   class  type   event   number 
2018-10-02T10:19:48+00:00  NOTIFICATION  Access Control  Window/Door -61
```

could anyone help me out, Thanks in advance

Comment: Is your data already stored as dictionary, or string?

Comment: @TeeKea yeah its string

Comment: If you are reading json data from a file, or a string, then my answer below should help you.

Comment: @TeeKea python sensorTest.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sensorTest.py", line 18, in <module>
    tsv_writer.writerow(row.values())
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'values'                                                                     Im getting this error, please can i know what should be done

Comment: Okay, I see. Looks like you only have one data dictionary as you posted in your questions, right? If so, I would need to change my answer accordingly.

Comment: @TeeKea Yeah can you check it

Comment: Can you check my updated answer (the code in the bottom)?

Comment: If it doesn't work, can you please post an extended sample of your json file?

Comment: Please mark the answer as **Accepted** if it worked for you. If not, tell us your current problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it's the same as converting JSON to csv, but instead of using the *comma* you can use *tab* as a delimeter, as follows:

```
import json
import csv

# input data
json_file = open("data.json", "r")
json_data = json.load(json_file)
json_file.close()

data = json.loads(json_data)

tsv_file = open("data.tsv", "w")
tsv_writer = csv.writer(tsv_file, delimiter='\t')

tsv_writer.writerow(data[0].keys()) # write the header

for row in data: # write data rows
    tsv_writer.writerow(row.values())

tsv_file.close()
```

The above code will work if you json file has multiple data rows. If you have only one data row, the below code should work for you:

```
tsv_writer.writerow(data.keys()) # write the header
tsv_writer.writerow(data.values()) # write the values
```

Hope this helps.